# Get Text from<p> using HttpAgilityPack

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, html-agility-pack

I am using this code to return text from html "P" tag

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(content);
string query = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p/text()").InnerText;
            if (query.Length >0)
            {
                query = query.Substring(0, 60) + "...";
            }
```

>
Here the problem is if the "P" tag contains another tag this will not return text. for Ex.

```
<p><img src="http://localhost:49171/Images/MyImages/80ef7d03-6a8b-49e2-a4da-fa9f5f1773dd.jpg" alt="" />Thank you for choosing Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro. This is a license agreement between you and Microsoft Corporation (or, based on where you live, one of its affiliates) </p>
```

in my code, query returns "Images/MyImages/80ef7d03-6a8b-49e2-a4da-fa9f5f1773dd.jpg",

Anybody please help me to retrive these lines "Thank you for choosing Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro."
   instead of "Images/MyImages/80ef7d03-6a8b-49e2-a4da-fa9f5f1773dd.jpg".

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Since every text node in HtmlAgilityPack has the name `#text` you can do the following:

```
string query = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p")
    .First()
    .ChildNodes.First(node => node.Name == "#text").InnerText;
```

This takes the first `<p>` node in the document and selects the inner text of the first text node that is a direct child of the `<p>` node.